# InvalidOperationException when trying to add XElement to XDocument

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml, windows-phone-8

I'm getting this error when I try to add a XElement to a XDocument:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

My code is:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage
Imports System.IO

Public Sub SaveRecord()
        Using myIsolatedStorage As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()

            Dim doc As XDocument
            Using isoStore1 As IsolatedStorageFile = _
                    IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()

                Using isoStream1 As IsolatedStorageFileStream = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Open, isoStore1)
                    doc = XDocument.Load(isoStream1)

                    MessageBox.Show(doc.ToString)
                    'This gives the right xml-code


                    doc.Add(New XElement("NewChild", "new content")) 'This is where the error takes place
                    MessageBox.Show(doc.ToString)
                    Using isoStore As IsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()

                        Using isoStream As IsolatedStorageFileStream = New IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.xml", FileMode.Create, isoStore)
                            doc.Save(isoStream)
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

        End Using

        Exit Sub

    End Sub
```

The error shows up when the debugger enters the line `doc.Add(New XElement("NewChild", "new content"))`

Can anyone explain to me what the cause of this error is and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your `XElement` to your `XDocument`s root.

```
doc.Root.Add(New XElement("NewChild", "new content"))
```

Adding it directly to the doc will make your `xml` invalid as it will be having two roots because you are adding the `XElement` after your `XDocument` instead of to the root.